# Matplotlib / Mplfinance - how to change line width

Tags: matplotlib, mplfinance, linewidth

maybe someone knows what I need add here to change line width?

```
mpf.plot(df4, type='candle', style='yahoo', volume=True, hlines=[12,4],  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical and horizontal lines can be set in dictionary format. Line widths are specified in tuple format.

```
mpf.plot(df, 
         type='candle',
         style='yahoo',
         volume=True, 
         hlines=dict(hlines=[12,4], linewidths=(2,3.5)))
```

[image]